# Send socket from python to Meteor (node.js)

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, meteor

I want to send a socket with data (just an integer like "23") from python to a web app that is written using [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) which is a web framework built on top of node.js and other libraries.

On python side i have the following code:

```
import serial, socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("localhost", 3000))
s.send ('something')
```

What do I have to do on Meteor side? Is this python code correct? Is this different from websockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor uses the DDP protocol to communicate, so you would have to write a DDP client for Python and either CALL a remote Meteor method or SUB to a published channel.

Some initial work on a python DDP client has been done, but not finished, here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/unfinished/python-ddp-client/ddp-client.py

Comment: Thanks, I just tried python-ddp-client right now and the command SUB is working but CALL is not. CALL is for calling methods, right? But methods that are on the client or on the server?

Comment: CALL is for calling server methods that you define with `Meteor.methods`.